# How to use onbeforeunload in Dart

Tags: javascript, dart

In JavaScript it's possible to open a confirm dialog before closing the window.

Example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   return "Please don't go!";
};
```

How can you achieve the same in Dart?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653326/alert-before-unload-in-dart-m8

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [handling events](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html) section of this page and [this api](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/BeforeUnloadEvent.html), perhaps try:

```
window.onBeforeUnload.listen((e) {
    return "Don't go!";
});
```

Sorry, I'm not an expert on Dart, but maybe this puts you on the right track?

Also consider jQuery:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    return "Don't go!";
});
```

Comment: Yup, here's the API docs: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Window.html#onBeforeUnload

Comment: the dart snippet is not correct, as method `listen` expects a `void Function(Event)` so you can't return a `String`. You should do something like this: `if (event is BeforeUnloadEvent) event.returnValue = "Don't go!";`