# How to prevent onBeforeUnload listener in dart from prompting the user?

Tags: dart, dart2js

I basically want just to listen for 'onbeforeunload' to make sure the user won't receive 'connection lost' error messages from my ajax calls. i therefore registered an event and simply set a variable to true that i know to not bother the user with further error messages:

```
window.onBeforeUnload.listen((BeforeUnloadEvent e){
  isUnloading = true;
});
```

in Dartium this works, after running dart2js i get a javascript alert with 'false': [image]

according to [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802290/how-to-use-onbeforeunload-in-dart) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653326/alert-before-unload-in-dart-m8), to set the text I would have to set e.returnValue = 'Prompt'; - but what should i do if I do NOT want to show any dialog? - according to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload) the prompt is shown for every non-void return value.. but how can i set returnValue to void? (null is not working) - is this a bug, or am i doing it wrong? (dart sdk 1.0.0.7)

Comment: It's an issue: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16215

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to prevent this dialog in Chrome if you subscribe to onBeforeUnload.
You can try the onPageHide event (works in Chrome, may not work in other browsers).